# SQL query to find names of Employess living in the same city

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

[Image of the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlwtR.png)

I am trying to output Employee names for employees who live in the same city.

It should not be like `where city='Pune'` or anything static.

If a City occurs more than once then display the name of employees living in that city.

Expected Output

```
| eid | ename    | city   
+-----+----------+--------  
|   2 | Abhishek | Pune   
|   1 | Amitab   | Pune  
|   4 | Amy      | Mumbai  
|   5 | John     | Mumbai  
|   3 | Rupali   | Mumbai  
|   7 | Sachin   | Satara  
|   6 | Sachin   | Satara
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. PS Show  parts you can do. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Your paragraph explaining what you want is unintelligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select city, group_concat(distinct ename)
from emp
group by city

Answer (score -1):

**SELECT** city **FROM** employe_table **WHERE** city='pune' **OR** city='mumbai';

Comment: The question explicitly says not to name specific cities. PS Please read the edit help about how to format code. PS Code-only answers are poor. [answer] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).